# Is ASP.NET Core 6 Web API compatible with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, .net-6.0

I have a class library project which has EF 6 (6.4.4 as listed on the dll) and makes calls to a test database which returns data.

I have a test web project where I can create an ASP.NET Web API 2 project and calling the URL returns results.

I decided to go with .NET 6 for a new functionality in a new project.

So I took these steps:

1. Add a new ASP.NET Core Web API and select .NET 6.
2. I can run the weather application within the project.
3. I now add a reference into this newly created project from the existing project which is using EF 6.
4. I come across a few errors and after a few installations of various bits all is compiling and running. This is how my dependencies look like

[image]

I create a controller and then reference the relevant instances of classes I require to test (in short the same code as I had in the test project I mentioned above). I run the new .NET 6 app and the swagger window shows the methods I created and when running the default method it runs but seems to return all of the entities instead of the one table......

I then navigate to the URL where I created the controller and it returns 0 rows (or [] in a browser).

I re-run the tests in Postman and exactly the same issue. I change this default method and create a manual row using a List and this displays in this new app and Postman.

I return back to the original code and debug it. I noticed it goes into the project which I added a reference for but it returns 0 records.

I decided to go back to the test Web API project I created above and using the same code it returns rows back.

I compare the versions of EF in the .NET 6 project and my primary project where all the calls go to and both are 6.4.4.

Is there some compatibility issue here or can a .NET 6 project not be used in this manner?

When I run `dotnet --info` I see

[image]

Comment: You can't use EF 6 in NET 6

Comment: Ah, ok.... so by that i can assume you mean i cant reference a .Net 4.72 project using EF 6 in a .Net 6 project in this manner? Only way to go about this is to go back to a prior version of WebAPI etc?

Comment: No problem with EF 6 in .NET 6

Comment: All your projects must be .NET Standard or .NET 3 or later

Comment: @ErikEJ Right so if i install .Net Core 3.1 as part of Visual Studio 2022 using this link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk it "should" get me on track? This way my existing project would be able to run EF6 and Web Core should be able to utilise the same project?

Comment: I use a Net Standard project for my entities and classes that use a db connection. That way I can target both EF Core and EF6 and use that library for all projects.

Comment: Just use .NET 6. No need to mix with 3 now

Comment: Im a little confused as to what i should be doing. I was looking into upgrading the project containing the Entities etc from .Net X to .Net Standard/ 6 as i dont see the option for .Net 6 but running dotnet -- info shows the results in my original post now.

Comment: @GHDevOps: you definitely **can** use EF 6.4.4 in NET6, we have multiple apps doing this, no issues. You possibly can't use an old .NET Framework assembly that references EF6 in .NET6 but the two, using EF6 and using an assembly that uses EF6, are separate issues.

Comment: Until you need Identity and UserManager

Comment: @GHDevOps: true, but your first comment is still misleading.

Comment: Not misleading you're just having a bad day!

Comment: @GHDevOps No, your first comment on this question is demonstrably false. It's possible to use EF 6 in .NET 6, therefore your comment is wrong and you should remove it. If you want to post a more nuanced comment like `You can use EF 6 in .NET 6, but beware some things built on top of it such as the old Identity will not work` then feel free. Please don't accuse others of having a bad day when they're ultimately trying to make sure that accurate information is provided here.